# Updating Python version from command prompt and Conversion from PyQt4 to PyQt5

Tags: linux, python-3.x, pyqt4, pyqt5

Running: Ubuntu 16.04 and Python 3.5.2

So I ran a script which I found here: https://github.com/rferrazz/pyqt4topyqt5
in order to convert one of my projects built in PyQt4 into a PyQt5 project.

I ran the script and the conversion was made just fine with no errors. Essentially, everywhere QtGui() was used was changed to QtWidgets(). The only problem, when I try to run the new PyQt5 project I get the following error:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyQt5/QtGui.so: undefined symbol: PySlice_AdjustIndices
```

I am not positive but it seemed to me this would be a version error of some kind, which brings me to my questions. Is there a method of updating Python from 3.5 to the newest version release which I believe is 3.7 from the command prompt? Also, is the ImportError I got a version control issue like I believe it to be?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem ended up being a version problem from what I can tell. I installed py3.7 from source using pyenv, drove the script with that interpreter through PyCharm and was able to run it.